# How to preserve "Character Reference Codes"(&lt;) while reading content from XML file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, saxparser

I have used below code to read content from xml file

```
public static void toXSD() {
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document document;
        try {
            document = saxBuilder.build(new File("D:\\Users\\schintha\\Desktop\\Work\\\test_files\\SUMMARY_11.xml"));
            for (Element element : document.getRootElement().getChildren()) {
                System.out.println("Name = " + element.getName());
                System.out.println("Value = " + element.getValue());
                System.out.println("Text = " + element.getText());                  
            }        
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}}
```

My input file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<temp>
   <position>&lt;</position>   
</temp>
```

Output is

```
Name = position
Value = <
Text = <
```

In this regard , i request to let me know how to retrieve `&lt;` as is,  instead of "<".since it is not starting of tag but a value of tag "position"

Comment: < is not starting of a tag either, unless your console is setup to be XML. < is just the character <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  text-commons `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` class `escapeXml10` method, we can escape the character reference codes in the xml tags -
`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(element.getValue())`

Full example is shown below

```
public static void toXSD() {
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document document;
        try {
            document = saxBuilder.build(new File("D:\\Users\\schintha\\Desktop\\Work\\\test_files\\SUMMARY_11.xml"));
            for (Element element : document.getRootElement().getChildren()) {
                System.out.println("Name = " + element.getName());
                System.out.println("Value = " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(element.getValue()));                                  
            }        
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}}
```

Same input file used in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<temp>
   <position>&lt;</position>   
</temp>
```

got expected output is(value of position tag without parsing)

```
Name = position
Value = &lt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's the job of a parser to decode such things and give you the underlying data irrespective of how it was represented. `&lt;` represents the character `<` so that's what the parser gives you.